# Give all users of an AWS account access to an EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I have created an EKS cluster. At the moment only I can access it via `kubectl`. I want to give all my colleges access to it. We all have users in the same AWS account.

If I understood the documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html correctly, I have to add every user separately.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2):

By adding the account to the `mapAccounts` section in the `aws-auth` config map you only get authentication.

This means kubernetes will assign your IAM-user's arn -something like: arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/myIAMUser- to the kubernete's `username` but you don't get any rights to do anything, not even listing pods.

Additionally you would have to create (Cluster)RoleBindings to give the rights to the user.

For example, to give the previous user read-only access to all namespaces we create a `ClusterRoleBinding` containing the following:

```
# This role binding allows the user to read in all namespaces.
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
    name: myIAMUser-readOnly
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/myIAMUser
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: view
```

More information about the user facing roles defined in kubernetes can be found in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#user-facing-roles).

Another possible solution would be to edit the `mapUsers` section in the `aws-auth` config map. I don't like this approach because you have to modify the `aws-auth` config map each time you want to add a user and you could, by mistake, modify other parts of the file or corrupt the contents. Also adding or deleting role bindings is easier to automatize than editing an existing file.

More information about the format of the `aws-auth` config map can be found [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator/blob/master/README.md).

**---UPDATE---**

Instead of creating cluster role bindings for every user you can just make use of the `system:authenticated` group like this:

```
# This role binding allows the user to read in all namespaces.
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
    name: authenticatedUsers-readOnly
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Group
  name: system:authenticated
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: view
```

By the way, that cluster role binding can be created like this: `kubectl create clusterrolebinding authenticatedUsers-readOnly --clusterrole=view --group=system:authenticated`.

You could even not touch the `aws-auth` config map at all -no need to modify the `mapAccounts`- and create a cluster role binding with read only permissions for authenticated and unauthenticated users by issuing: `kubectl create clusterrolebinding authenticatedUsers-readOnly --clusterrole=view --group=system:authenticated --group=system:unauthenticated`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to use `mapAccounts` in the `aws-auth` config map.

See documentation here on the aws-iam-authenticator.

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator/blob/master/README.md

By using mapAccounts, you map all IAM users into the eks cluster; and if the users have the correct IAM permissions to connect then they should be able to authenticate.